# Data modelling for 'followers count' in MongoDB app with RESTful API

Tags: api, mongodb, rest

I have a `User` entity which has an array of other user IDs he/she is following.

```
var userSchema = {
  following: { type: Array }
};
```

I have a RESTful API, and when I request a `User`, my application needs to know how many followers that `User` has.

The two options I see are:

- When a `User` is requested, do a count query such as: `{ following: { $in: [userId] } }`
- When a `User` is `POST`ed, check to see whether any user IDs were added or removed to the `following` array, and if they were, use MongoDB's `$inc` to increment or decrement a `followersCount` property on the `User` document that have been followed/unfollowed.

Are they any other options? If not, what would be the best option? I feel slightly weird about putting a `followersCount` property in the document itself, because this suggests it can be updated by the application, when in fact it is just a dynamic count.

I have a similar situation where I need my RESTful API to return the number of `article`s that are associated with a `website`. Do I count the articles for that website on request, or do I store a count property and update it every time a new article associated with that website is created?

Comment: You probably want to consider (and include in the question) what your read/write loads are - how you use the data and the requirements around responsiveness/latency are critical when deciding on schema in MongoDB (and in all non-relational systems).

Comment: " I feel slightly weird about putting a followersCount property in the document itself, because this suggests it can be updated by the application, when in fact it is just a dynamic count." I felt the same way, and 'solved' it by having an object `c` of calculated in the document in which I put all calculated fields, `followersCount` in this case. It gives some (mental) seperation of concerns although it's not air-tight of course. Recalculation using background jobs only execute on `c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be scared of storing more data than you think you need in a document. When I started thinking along the lines of mongo, rather than a RDMS, I was freed from thinking *normalize everything*. It allowed me to add more 'useful' information into a document, even if it wans't strictly necessary. Transactions within a document are cheap, and the cost of storage is relatively cheap as well. The cost in finding information in another document or collection is expensive (processing wise) and possibly worth mitigating if you can.

I understand your concern about having a count in the db that 'the application can edit'. So what? Make sure your application can't edit it, and if your API is open to the world, make sure they can't edit it either. The usefulness of 'cached' count far outweighs the fact that it could potentially be edited and fall out of sync. This is one of the dangers of using a nosql database: things could end up out of sync, since we're trusting the application code to keep data in good order, rather than relying on the database.

Consider this. What if a user gets removed, and a count doesn't get updated. Will that make the world of a difference to a user? Possibly not. While I like the idea of a background task to check values (and it is worth having something like that), another solution would be to check the integrity everytime the user posts something to the followers. In that case you have to get all the users anyway, and so its relatively inexpensive to check the count as well. Essentially you're building in a failsafe that checks data integrity everytime a message is sent from the user. If the user never sends, that user probably doesn't care if the count is 100% accurate.

At the end of the day, if your code is well tested, and defensive coding practices are followed, you shouldn't have any consistency problems.

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to do it is the right way. One of advantages to something like MongoDB is that you can embed data to reduce the queries you need to run on a page. Which is what you're doing by caching the followers count.

Both of your options work, it's just about the tradeoffs you want to make.

1) Less efficient, but the most accurate. Any sort of desync that somehow occurs will be fixed when they next follow someone. This is a decent way to start off and then change it later if the follower counts or the user database gets large.

2) Most efficient, you need to make sure you always call $inc when changing the follower count or it'll become desynced until you do #1.

Alternatively, you can do #2 and then run a reconciliation job in the background that will resync it on the offhand chance it does become desynced. You can do this easily with the [MongoDB aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/), you can speed up the reconciliation job by using a timestamp in the `User` collection and only recalculating the followers for those who were updated since the last time the job ran.

To expand as the original question was updated:

In general, if you can avoid doing a `count()`, you should.

Nothing is wrong with starting off using `count()` and then swap to a more efficient solution (#2) later on. Caching the `count()` results somewhere like memcache can also be used to reduce performance issues until you stop using `count()` directly.

Comment: How would a desync occur with option one? Do you think MongoDB is appropriate if this was to scale to thousands of users?

Comment: If you were running replication, a query against a slave could be inaccurate due to replication lag. If you're never going to run replication, then it shouldn't really be possible to desync. As for scaling, it depends on what your server is, but thousands of users is fine. The only issue is that Mongo can be slow at counting, so it's something to watch. It's not an issue you would need to worry too much about in all likelihood.

Comment: it's possible to be out of sync if the same thread updates following array but then dies before incrementing a counter on the user add/removed (note that array reflects whom this user is following, and count is kept on how many users are following a specific user so it's not redundant information in the same document).   You also could have the "maintenance" job use aggregation framework rather than map/reduce - it'll be much faster.

Comment: That kind of case is going to be rather rare. It's not a bad idea to have a recollection phase that runs every once in a while just in case if you're that paranoid. But having the request die mid way will not really happen provided you aren't doing things like doing a SIGKILL.

Comment: of course it could happen - the process itself doesn't have to die, maybe mongod will be brought down - there is no transaction mechanism to make sure that two separate writes are always performed "together".

Comment: The same case still applies. If you're doing things properly, mongod having a hard exit is not going to be a common situation. If that is a common occurrence, then there is something else going on that should be looked into. That doesn't mean a reconciliation job is a bad idea either way.